# “It will be” vs. “Chances are it will be"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across a question which has two expressions: "Chances are it will be" and "it will be”. Are they different?

Here is the fill-in-the-blank question:

> Next time you are in a lift, look for the name of the people who made it. _________ the Otis Elevator Company.
>
> A. Chances are it will be
>   B. It will be
>   C. May be

My answer is B but the answer is A.  Anyone who can explain to me?

Comment: A and B are both grammatically correct.  A is identified (by the test makers) as the better answer on extra-grammatical grounds, namely, that  Otis does not have a world monopoly on elevators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [(the) chances are](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/chances-are)
>   informal
>   ​it is likely:
>   *Chances are (that) they'll be late anyway.*
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

So option A implies

> It is likely that it will be the Otis Elevator Company.

Option A suggests that there is a high chance that the name is "Otis Elevator Company".

Option B

> It will be the Otis Elevator Company.

suggests that it is guaranteed that the name is "Otis Elevator Company".

As you can imagine, there are likely many elevator companies, so it is not guaranteed that "Otis Elevator Company" is the name on the elevator. Instead, if it is the case that Otis Elevator Company is a very popular manufacturer, then its name is *likely* on the elevator. I assume there is a passage and it goes on to discuss this. So the answer is A.

Answer (score -2):

"Chances are it will be" is a probable condition - something that they aren't sure  of; but, highly probable.

It's not "May be" because there is high probability of it being Otis Elevator Company.

And it is not 100% either- so it isn't "It will be".

Comment: It is not "May be" because the sentence would then lack a subject.

Comment: It's  not "May be". That's what I had told too.